# 'uri.match' is undefined trying to require audio file into video source

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-video

Here is my code around this `<Video />` element

```
class Menu extends Component {
    ...
    audioFile = null
    componentWillMount(){
        this.audioFile = require('../../assets/audio/subtle.mp3');
    }
}

<Video source={{uri: this.audioFile}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
  ref={(ref) => {
    this.player = ref
  }}
  onError={this.audioError} 
  audioOnly
  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
  playInBackground
  playWhenInactive
  ignoreSilentSwitch={"ignore"}  
/>
```

The specific error I get is...

```
TypeError: uri.match is not a function. (In 'uri.match(/^\//)', 'uri.match' is undefined)
```

Here are the versions

`expo: 30.0.0`

`expokit: 1.7.1`

`react: 16.3.1`

`react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz`

`react-native-video: 3.2.1`

I'm trying to load an audio asset from the local package here, but I can't seem to get it to work, if I remove the audio file from that folder it throws an error that it can't find it so it's definitely finding the file.

Would love some help with this

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @KishanBharda yes, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what made it work in my use case

`<Video source={require('../../assets/audio/file.mp3')} ... />`

Comment: Ok. This is nice one. Can you tell me how can I display video when I have uri like `photos://23E23...`?

Comment: If the photo is on your device I believe you just use the URI bit. I haven't attempted to display a photo in this way before. I know that you can display base64 images with `{uri: 'data:...'}` so if you can get the base64 image data which I believe you can from a local photo lookup you could display it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The variable `audioFile` itself contains the `uri` key.

So instead of

```js
<Video source={{uri: this.audioFile}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
  ...
  ...
/>
```

try this :

```js
<Video source={this.audioFile}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
  ...
  ...
/>
```

Please notice that I have directly passed the `this.audioFile` to the source.

**And more important thing is that, to display video you must have to pass height and width.**